# Why does this JavaScript and WebRTC code not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webrtc, ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vid Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video autoplay>

    </video>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        var constrainsts = {
            audio: true,
            video: true
        };
        var videoArea = $("video");
        navigator.getUserMedia(constrainsts, results, error);

        function results(stream) {
            videoArea.srcObject = stream;
            videoArea[0].play();
        }

        function error() {
            console.log("we messed up");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using express to serve this as an ejs file. Why does it not work? I am using node.js, express, and ejs. Did I do something wrong? It doesn't give any error neither.

Answer (score 2):

navigator.getUserMedia is deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

Try this instead navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()

Answer (score 2):

getUserMedia requires a secure context, i.e. https. See [here](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2019/getusermedia-can-no-longer-be-used-on-insecure-sites/)